# Authenticate user by ADFS (Active Directory Federation Service)

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, adfs2.0

I need to check whether particular user exist OR not in Active Directory by `ADFS`.

So, I want my *ADFS* to `check user Authentication` *by UserName/Password.*

Could anybody please provide the sample code OR tutorial for the same.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are actually asking two questions here: Can ADFS check if a user exists in the Active Directory and Can I authenticate at the ADFS using username and password.

Answer (score 5):

To use Username/Password authentication you can use the

> trust/13/UsernameMixed

endpoint of the ADFS 2.0.

This does NOT check if the user exists in the Active Directory!

In code you request the token like this:

```
WSTrustChannelFactory adfsfactory = new WSTrustChannelFactory(new UserNameWSTrustBinding(SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential),
                            StsEndpoint);

adfsfactory.TrustVersion = TrustVersion.WSTrust13;

// Username and Password here...
factory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = "domain\username";
factory.Credentials.UserName.Password = "password";

IWSTrustChannelContract channel = adfsfactory.CreateChannel();

// request the token
SecurityToken token = channel.Issue(rst);
```

Then create the channel factory for your service using your token:

```
var binding = new WS2007FederationHttpBinding(WSFederationHttpSecurityMode.Message);

var factory = new ChannelFactory<IYourInterface >(binding, "your service address");

factory.ConfigureChannelFactory();

IYourInterface channel = factory.CreateChannelWithIssuedToken(token);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I believe this will check for Authentication... Do you think that ADFS is exposing API to just check that whether particular user exist OR not by given credential (e.g. email/password) ??

Comment: Yes, as I wrote in the post you can use this to authenticate. As far as I know ADFS does not have a feature that allows you to check if a user exists. You could write a very simple webservice to check if a user exists, or even a website.

Comment: LdapConnection.UserExists(UserName); Is maybe what you are looking for.

Comment: Does anyone know how to do this in .NET 4.5? UserNameWSTrustBinding is gone, I think?

Answer (score 1):

The AD FS 2.0 sign-in pages support username/password authentication out of the box.  No code or customizations necessary.

Answer (score 0):

As per @Marnix, this is out the box behavior.

However, just to point out:

Authenticating the user is NOT the same as checking whether a particular user exists in Active Directory.

e.g. the user could be locked out. He still exists in AD but will not be able to authenticate.