# How to access AD FS claims by User's credential?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services, adfs2.0

As I am developing a WCF web service to make an intermediator between user's login action and their active directory roles and permissions. I don't want my host application to directly talk to AD FS. I want any host application to use my web service and it will provided necessary information on the basis of given credential.

In my web method I need to get claims from AD FS (WIF) by user's login credentials.

My web method will have two input parameters, the Window User's Email Id / Windows Account Name and the Password.

So, I want to access AD FS claims in my web method by given user's credential.

How would I get AD FS claims by given user's credential?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could request a DisplayTokem from the ADFS and work with that, it's basically the same information you have in the token.

```
public DisplayClaimCollection GetDisplayClaims(string username, string password)
        {
            WSTrustChannelFactory factory = null;
            try
            {

                // use a UserName Trust Binding for username authentication
                factory = new WSTrustChannelFactory(
                    new UserNameWSTrustBinding(SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential),
                    "https://.../adfs/services/trust/13/usernamemixed");

                factory.TrustVersion = TrustVersion.WSTrust13;


                factory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = username;
                factory.Credentials.UserName.Password = password;


                var rst = new RequestSecurityToken
                              {
                                  RequestType = RequestTypes.Issue,
                                  AppliesTo = "Relying party endpoint address",
                                  KeyType = KeyTypes.Symmetric,
                                  RequestDisplayToken = true
                              };

                IWSTrustChannelContract channel = factory.CreateChannel();
                RequestSecurityTokenResponse rstr;
                SecurityToken token = channel.Issue(rst, out rstr);

                return rstr.RequestedDisplayToken.DisplayClaims;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (factory != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        factory.Close();
                    }
                    catch (CommunicationObjectFaultedException)
                    {
                        factory.Abort();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

But this is not the proper way of doing it! 
You should use your RelyingParty certificate to decrypt the encrypted token and read the claims from it.

Comment: @Floarin Thanks very much for your answer. There are 2 things I am getting here....  1) [rstr.RequestedDisplayToken.DisplayClaims;] Here, RequestedDisplayToken is not available with my SecurityToken object. I am getting the compilation error.  2) Could you please let me know I would either use RelyingParty certificate to encrypt/decrypt token and read the claims by code??  Thanks in advace!

Comment: @nunu: I changed the code, you have to add the AppliesTo Address yourself, what is the compilation error you get? I will check about the token decrypt code now.

Comment: @Floarin, Please skip my point no. 1 for now.. The compilation error got resolved.... yes.. Please let me know your thoughts on point no. 2   Thanks!

Comment: @Floarin, Thanks very much for your answer! The compilation error got resolved, it was there just because of I didn't declared [RequestSecurityTokenResponse] object.. So it's got resolved... but please provide me some information on encrypt/decrypt the token and read the claims by it.. Looking forward for your reply! Thanks..

Comment: I don't have source code to decrypt a token, usually you don't have to worry about that as WIF does it for you. Have a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa967562(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Thanks @Florin, Last question.. Can I use [token.ID] as a unique id for my transaction purpose??

Comment: The SecurityToken has a TokenXML property, this is a XmlLinkedNode which contains the encrypted data.

Comment: I am not sure if it is a good idea to use the token id for transactions, I don't know which transactions you need.

Comment: @Floarin, There will not be a special transaction. I was just thinking that as It's a UNIQUE id in the span, so I could use this ID for unique user's transaction Id.. Please correct me if ID will not be a unique for different channel.Issue() call..

Comment: @nunu: According to msdn the Token.ID is unique for each token. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.tokens.securitytoken.aspx. To answer your question: You get unique token id for each channel.Issue() call.

Comment: @Florin, Can I get cookie from this? I want to get cookie from ADFS so I can response back my result with cookie from my web method response.. so my web API client can use this cookie for their form based authentication? so, How would I get cookie from AD FS ?? Thanks in advance !! and other question is.. Can I check whether particular user exist or not by in Active directory by Windows Account name [domain\account name] from AD FS?

Comment: @nunu I don't know how to get a cookie, but I suggest you create a new question, so other people can find it, too. I already tried to answer your second question in your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10651304/authenticate-user-by-adfs-active-directory-federation-service (check my comments)

Comment: I am getting an error ID3082: The request scope is not valid or is unsupported. I am not sure if ADFS is properly configured.

Answer (score 7):

You should perform a web service call to the https://.../adfs/services/trust/13/usernamemixed endpoint of AD FS 2.0 which uses Integrated Windows Authentication, providing the user's credentials so that the connection can be set up.  On this endpoint, call the http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/RST/Issue operation.  (More details are in [section 4.1 of the WS-Trust 1.3 specification](https://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/ws-trust-1.3-os.html#_Requesting_a_Security_Token).)  The input for this operation is a RequestSecurityToken request.  The response contains a SAML token containing the claims you require.

Note that the AD FS 2.0 WSDL is avaible at https://.../adfs/services/trust/mex: if you point your Visual Studio [Add Service Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628652.aspx) wizard, or your Java [wsimport](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/wsimport.html), to that URL then you'll easily generate client code which you can use for performing the RST Issue operation.

Comment: Hello @Marnix, I have used [SecurityToken token = channel.Issue(rst);] to issue security token, but it doesn't provide me the claims. Could you please do let me know that How could I get claims by 'https://.../adfs/services/trust/13/usernamemixed' calls?

Comment: OK, so you're definitely on the right track.  Unfortunately, I don't know enough of the WCF security model to help you further here; sorry.

Comment: I believe WCF is not the case here either, Let's assume that I am developing the service by the new feature of Asp.Net MVC 4 - a Web API.. Can we get the claims from AD FS if I use MVC4 Web API ?