# Accessing to AD FS 2.0 Claims through wcf

Tags: wcf, wif, adfs2.0

Currently I'm developing a WCF Service that act as inter-mediator between ASP application and AD FS 2.0, because the architech don't want that ASP app talk directly with AD FS 2.0.

He want that any app to use the WCF Service and this service will provide the information (Claims) without using the STS configuration of Visual Studio.

So, I found this code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10992474/516715

This work fine to get claims, but I have questions about this:

- How create Authentication, session and persistent cookies of ADFS in ASP app?
- How close the session through the WCF service.
- Exists more details to keep in mind about this case?
- Exists security problems with this?
- Could anybody have suggestions on this?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you elaborate more on this "doesn't want the application to talk to adfs". The truth is, the application NEVER talks to adfs, it is the user's browser which does so.

Comment: Hi @WiktorZychla, of course. In this case instead of using STS configuration, to use the the WCF Service to provide the information. It's right?

Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like an unnecessary complication.

Comment: @WiktorZychla I think the same :) Do you think that it's necessary programming a custom STS to cover all of this?. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would say you are opening yourself up to a whole world of pain.

There is an established, security reviewed, gold standard pattern for applications to communicate via a browser to ADFS using WIF.

So what you are essentially trying to do is re-invent the wheel by writing a web service that implements all the browser functionality e.g cookies. Your solution loses all the advantages that ADFS provides e.g. SSO, Federation, HRD etc.

And now you want to dig the hole deeper by writing your own STS.

The browser pattern is exactly what Microsoft use for Windows Live, Office 365 and Azure Active Directory.

So if it's good enough for Microsoft, why does your architect not want it?