# OWIN Use Forms authentication and WSFederated authentication through ADFS

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, owin, forms-authentication, adfs, katana

I am trying to implement this solution where internal  organizational users would login through a login form(but use windows credentials) that post's to ADFS and get the claims. Also allow external users (who are created in backend and inserted into sql server database), whose information contain same claims as from ADFS. Kind of multiple login provider systems like below, when i input username and password on left it validated against SQL Server but clicking windows would redirect to login onto adfs.
 [image: Multiple Login]

Right now i got the code like below, but by default it tries to redirect to the adfs URL than show the login screen.

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(App_Start.Startup))]
namespace App_Start
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                //interactive logon process
                AuthenticationMode = Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationMode.Active,
                //name of the authentication type
                AuthenticationType = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
                //Login path should be below
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Home/Login"),
                //TODO: Enable this to always send and receive cookies in SSL when in production
                CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.Always,
                //enable sliding expiration
                SlidingExpiration = true,
                //Cookie expires in 4 hours
                ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromTicks(DateTime.Now.AddHours(4).Ticks)
            });


            app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
             {
                 MetadataAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["federationUri"],
                 Wtrealm = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["realm"]
             });

            //This will set ADFS as the default authentication provider 
            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That won't work, you can't use the passive ADFS profile to "post" username/pwd there and expect it to not to show the login page.

Comment: @WiktorZychla thanks for responding. Is there a way i can do as stated ?

Comment: There is, manually http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10981065/how-to-access-ad-fs-claims-by-users-credential