# Authentication in C# with Active Directory

Tags: c#, security, authentication, active-directory

I am trying to create an application that requires user authentication over active directory to return a token, but I am not sure how to use it correctly.

I've been looking at [Authenticate user by ADFS (Active Directory Federation Service)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10651304/authenticate-user-by-adfs-active-directory-federation-service) but I am not sure how to create a Request Security Token or how to use it correctly.

Are there any working examples for this available? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether you're using [WIF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748475.aspx) or .NET 4.5 `System.IdentityModel`.

Using WIF:

```
string endpointUri = string.Format("https://{0}/adfs/services/trust/13/usernamemixed", _serverName);

var factory = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrustChannelFactory(
              new UserNameWSTrustBinding(SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential),
              new EndpointAddress(endpointUri));

factory.TrustVersion = TrustVersion.WSTrust13;
if (factory.Credentials != null)
{
    factory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = "UserName";
    factory.Credentials.UserName.Password = "password";
}

var rst = new RequestSecurityToken
{
    RequestType = WSTrust13Constants.RequestTypes.Issue,
    AppliesTo = new EndpointAddress(_relyingPartyUri),
    KeyType = WSTrust13Constants.KeyTypes.Bearer,
};

var channel = factory.CreateChannel();
SecurityToken token = channel.Issue(rst);
return token;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using .NET 4.5 [System.IdentityModel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145031%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you'll need to define the UserNameWSTrustBinding yourself:

```
public class UserNameWSTrustBinding : WS2007HttpBinding
{
    public UserNameWSTrustBinding()
    {
        Security.Mode = SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential;
        Security.Message.EstablishSecurityContext = false;
        Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.UserName;
    }
}

string endpointUri = string.Format("https://{0}/adfs/services/trust/13/usernamemixed", _serverName);

var factory = new WSTrustChannelFactory(new UserNameWSTrustBinding(), endpointUri)
    {
        TrustVersion = TrustVersion.WSTrust13
    };

factory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = "UserName";
factory.Credentials.UserName.Password = "password";

var rst = new RequestSecurityToken
{
    RequestType = RequestTypes.Issue,
    AppliesTo = new EndpointReference(_relyingPartyUri),
    KeyType = KeyTypes.Symmetric
};

var channel = factory.CreateChannel();

return channel.Issue(rst);
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which type of application you are using.
Authentication over ADFS using WIF comes in two flavors:
- Passive authentication using Asp.net web form or MVC. You can refer to this article: [Claims Aware MVC4 App using WIF Identity and Access tool in .Net 4.5](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/distributedservices/archive/2013/10/01/claims-aware-mvc4-app-using-wif-identity-and-access-tool-in-net-4-5.aspx)

- Active authentication when the application is a Web Service like WCF. This article can help: [Claims Aware WCF using WIF in .Net 4.5](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/napegadie_kones_msft_blog/archive/2015/02/10/claims-aware-wcf-using-wif-in-net-4-5.aspx)

Also depending on the .NET framework you are using, you will need to download either one of the following:
- WIF Runtime and WIF SDK for .NET 4.0 
- Identity and Access Tool for .NET 4.5